# How to find all possible entities

Tags: xslt

I need to find some entities in xml files. These entities can be decimal, hexadecimal or named (common or my own).

**test.xml**

```
<test>Hello&#44;&nbsp;world&#33;</test>
```

I tried to use **test1.xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="//text()">
    <xsl:if test="matches(., '&amp;.*;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

or **test2.xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="//text()">
    <xsl:variable name="ent"><![CDATA[&.*;]]></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="matches(., $ent)">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

but got no result.

Is there a way to find entities using regular expressions?

Maybe there is a special text type that allows to use something like `matches(., _entities_)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the XSLT/XPath data model there are only text nodes with Unicode characters, using XSLT/XPath there is no way to know or find out whether the lexical markup of the document that was parsed into a tree contained an Unicode letter literally or as a character reference or as an entity reference. So XSLT is not the right tool for that, unless you use some preprocessor like http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/.